# How to SELECT MAX measure using MDX and return both Value and Date of Max Value

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have MDX Query Below:

```sql
WITH 
      MEMBER [Measures].[MaxValue] AS
      MAX([Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].Members, [Measures].[Sales Amount]) 
SELECT 
      {[Measures].[MaxValue]} ON COLUMNS
  
FROM
      [Adventure Works]
```

It returns Value:

> MaxValue
>
> $52,714,102.75

I want to return the both date and max value. I can achieve something similar with query below.

```sql
WITH 
      MEMBER [Measures].[MaxValue] AS
      MAX([Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].Members, [Measures].[Sales Amount]) 
SELECT 
      {[Measures].[Sales Amount],[Measures].[MaxValue]} ON COLUMNS,
      {[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].Members} ON ROWS 
FROM
      [Adventure Works]



+---------+----------------+----------------+
|         |  Sales Amount  |    MaxValue    |
+---------+----------------+----------------+
| FY 2005 | (null)         | $52,714,102.75 |
| FY 2006 | $23,360,526.01 | $52,714,102.75 |
| FY 2007 | $33,683,804.82 | $52,714,102.75 |
| FY 2008 | $52,714,102.75 | $52,714,102.75 |
| FY 2009 | $50,840.63     | $52,714,102.75 |
| FY 2010 | (null)         | $52,714,102.75 |
| FY 2011 | (null)         | $52,714,102.75 |
+---------+----------------+----------------+
```

My goal is to output below:

> FY 2008   $52,714,102.75  $52,714,102.75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you don't necessariy want to output both the Sales Amount and the MaxValue columns, as they have the same value. If you are looking to find the year with the max Sales Amount, the query below will do it.

```
SELECT 
      {[Measures].[Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS,
      ORDER({[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].Members},[Measures].[Sales Amount],DESC).ITEM(0) ON ROWS 
FROM
      [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternative to TheDumbRadish's answer:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,TopCount
  (
    [Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].MEMBERS
   ,1
   ,[Measures].[Sales Amount]
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```